# Best way to check columns in CSV

Tags: file, csv, validation, upload

I am currently loading CSV files to a production type system and I don't currently have a Dev DB to load to. The existing workflow is for the employee to search through the entire CSV to look for in correct entries examples- 1 column must be a price 00.00 and not include $, 1 column must only be numbers, 1 column must be between 5-7 numbers, one column can't be blank or 0 etc etc.

What is the best way for me to do this rather than filtering the CSV file in Excel and searching through the entire document. Note- I don't currently have visual studios or anything installed.

Thanks!

Comment: how's your python? you could write a CLI tool and use Python's Cerberus package to validate it https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/usage.html . or consider CSVKit's csvstat to analyze the file: https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvstat.html

Comment: If Python isn't you're thing,  Powershell handles CSV files quite nicely.  I've done lots of validation work like this in PowerShell.